# Animação Jquery em estilo toggle

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Ao clicar em um botão uma `div` aparece com o efeito subindo até o topo, com Jquery. Preciso que ao clicar novamente ela volte a sumir com a animação oposta - descendo. Como entendo pouco de JS, só consegui fazer com dois botões diferentes.

Tem uma maneira de fazer isso, no estilo de um `toggle` com apenas um botão?

Meu código até o momento:

```
$(".lyricshow").click(function () {    
    $(".lyricscreen").show()
    .animate({top:0}, function() {});
});
$(".lyricsclose").click(function () {    
    $(".lyricscreen").hide()
    .animate({bottom:0}, function() {});
});
```

Comment: Thiago da para fazer com apenas 1 botão e CSS, esse mesmo efeito! Sem jQuery nem JS, se quiser eu posto um exemplo na resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar [`.slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/), que é bem mais simples para esses casos do que `animate`. Veja:

```js
$(".lyricbutton").click(function(){    
    $(".lyricscreen").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.lyricscreen{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   display: none;
   background: yellow;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="lyricbutton" style="margin-left: 50px;">Abrir/Fechar</button>
<div class="lyricscreen">
   Olá!
</div>
```